# Cocos2d-x Pre-built Not Working At All! Not Found Available Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cocos2d-x

I am trying to do following ; http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/cocos2d-x/en/editors_and_tools/prebuilt_libraries.html

I got working copy of cocos2d-x 3.16.
I compiled the cpp-test everything is working fine.
I got VS2017.

But when i trying to create pre-built libraries this thing showed up. I could not find anything about it. Please help me guys!

**OUTPUT** :
`C:\>cocos gen-libs -c win32` 
`Not found VS2015`
`Not found VS2013`
`Not found available Visual Studio.`
`C:\>`

IMAGE :
[not found available visual studio.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHjCU.png)

Answer (score 1):

***The problem is 'gen-libs' can't find MSBuild.exe***

If you look in file utils.py

> ..\cocos2d-x-3.15.1\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\utils.py

In function **get_msbuild_path(vs_version)** :

```
def get_msbuild_path(vs_version):
# if cocos.os_is_win32():
#     import _winreg
# else:
#     return None

# if isinstance(vs_version, int):
#     # The value of vs_version is int. such as : 2013, 2015
#     if vs_version in VS_VERSION_MAP.keys():
#         vs_ver = VS_VERSION_MAP[vs_version]
#     else:
#         # not supported VS version
#         return None
# elif isinstance(vs_version, str):
#     # The value of vs_version is string. such as: "12.0", "14.0"
#     vs_ver = vs_version
# else:
#     return None

# # If the system is 64bit, find VS in both 32bit & 64bit registry
# # If the system is 32bit, only find VS in 32bit registry
# if cocos.os_is_32bit_windows():
#     reg_flag_list = [ _winreg.KEY_WOW64_32KEY ]
# else:
#     reg_flag_list = [ _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY, _winreg.KEY_WOW64_32KEY ]

# # Find VS path
# msbuild_path = None
# for reg_flag in reg_flag_list:
#     try:
#         vs = _winreg.OpenKey(
#             _winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
#             r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\%s" % vs_ver,
#             0,
#             _winreg.KEY_READ | reg_flag
#         )
#         msbuild_path, type = _winreg.QueryValueEx(vs, 'MSBuildToolsPath')
#     except:
#         continue

#     if msbuild_path is not None:
#         msbuild_path = os.path.join(msbuild_path, "MSBuild.exe")
#         if os.path.exists(msbuild_path):
#             break
#         else:
#             msbuild_path = None

# return msbuild_path
return os.path.join("C:","\Program Files (x86)", "Microsoft Visual Studio", "2017", "Community", "MSBuild" , "15.0", "Bin", "MSBuild.exe")
```

As you can see it is trying to find a suitable version of visual studio Build Tool using Registry Keys *'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions'* but registry entry isn't there.

What we can do instead is, comment this whole function and just return msbuild.exe path.

Notice the last line of above code snippet:

**`return os.path.join("C:","\Program Files (x86)", "Microsoft Visual Studio", "2017", "Community", "MSBuild" , "15.0", "Bin", "MSBuild.exe")`**

So, comment entire **def get_msbuild_path(vs_version)** function, and at the end add above return statement.

You might have to change above path if you have installed your visual studio in some other directory.

---

Next, open config file **gen_libs_config.json**

> ..\cocos2d-x-3.15.1\tools\cocos2d-console\plugins\plugin_generate\configs\gen_libs_config.json

and make sure at the end **'support_vs_versions'** looks like this

```
"support_vs_versions" : [ 2015, 2013, 2017 ]
```

if it doesn't has 2017, then add it & save.

---

Lastly, go to directory

> ..\cocos2d-x-3.15.1\tools\simulator\frameworks\runtime-src\proj.win32\

and open solution **simulator.sln** in Visual studio. On startup it will prompt to retarget all projects from an older version of Visual C++ to a newer one. Press **Yes**, and wait for visual studio to complete its work. Once the editor becomes idle. Close the solution.

---

Finally, try to run gen-libs command, like so:

```
cocos2d gen-libs -p win32 --vs 2017 -m debug
```